# Can Volley support deflate when parsing JSON object?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

When using Volley to connect to a url to get JSON data, this works fine:

```
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
        }
    });
```

However, if the data is compressed with "deflate", it errors out as it can't parse the characters of the downloaded data. I have to fall back on something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2500 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 24000;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);
            InflaterInputStream inflaterInputStream = new InflaterInputStream(url.openStream(), inflater);
            int count = inflaterInputStream.read(buffer);

            String jsonString = new String(buffer, 0, count, UTF8);
```

Which runs in its own thread and is difficult to fit into the framework. Is there a way I can use volley to either inflate automatically, or to be passed a parameter to know when to inflate if I know ahead an endpoint is compressed?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out an answer. Change the request to look like this:

```
    final CustomJsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
    }
});
```

And use this as a new class:

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;

public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
    private final JSONObject gson = new JSONObject();
    //private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;

    public CustomJSONObjectRequest(String url,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        //this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

//    @Override
//    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
//        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
//    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String stringResponse = new String(response.data);
            String encoding = response.headers.get("Content-Encoding");

            if (encoding != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                if (encoding.equals("gzip")) {

                    final GZIPInputStream gStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.data));
                    final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gStream);
                    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String read;
                    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(read);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    in.close();
                    gStream.close();

                    stringResponse = sb.toString();

                } else if (encoding.equals("deflate")) {

                    Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);
                    final InflaterInputStream inflaterInputStream = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.data), inflater);
                    final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inflaterInputStream);
                    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String read;
                    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(read);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    in.close();
                    inflaterInputStream.close();

                    stringResponse = sb.toString();
                }
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringResponse);

            return Response.success(
                    jsonObject,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(ex));
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(ex));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(ex));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to provide the Accept-Encoding in your Request so the server can respond correctly

`@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(super.getHeaders());
        headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "deflate, gzip, *");
        return headers;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
```

You are probably wasting the time saved before by sending GZIP.

My tests (huge files) are telling me that convert a string to jsonobject is a terrible waste of time.

The only way I see to improve times would be by getting the JSONObject directly without pass it to string, unzip and pass to JSONObject again.

I don't know if possible, but I didn't save any process time finally.